# How do I transfer a JS array to ANOTHER JS file

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a JS array from a JS file (file 1:`var array=["random","Stuff"]`) and I want to transfer it to another JS file (file 2: `array=["random","Stuff"]`). Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Could you provide a little more context? Are you just trying to describe import/require?

Comment: Not sure if I understood your question correctly, but there's no need to transfer variables between JS files. If your file1.js is added to your html before file2.js, array will automatically be available in file2.

Comment: Are you using Node.js? I recommend reading up on their [fs (file system)](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) api and searching for questions about file copy.

Answer (score 0):

OH BUMMER! I found the anwser in my head right after possting. Just add the file1
in the same html file as file2. Like this:

```
<head>
<script src="file1.js">
<script src="file2.js">
```

Comment: If you don’t think this question is useful to others (and don’t want to attract more downvotes), you can just delete it. https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question